# What is the best practice for multiple REST API calls with the same parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-restcontroller

I have a list of REST APIs which receive various parameters, which are aimed to search, filter and return data back to the front-end.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/api1", params = {"x,y,z,age,location"})
@GetMapping(value = "/api2", params = {"a,b,c,d,age,location"})
@GetMapping(value = "/api3", params = {"p,q,r,s,,age,location"})
@GetMapping(value = "/api4", params = {"p,q,r,s,,age,location"})
@GetMapping(value = "/api5", params = {"p,q,r,s,,age,location"})
```

As you can notice, the problem is that there are a few parameters (age,location), which are common for all these endpoints.

The plan is we might need to introduce a new parameter like 'gender' to all these endpoints.
Is there a best practice to handle these common parameters across the APIs so that we don't need to modify each Controller and add the newly added request parameter?

The controller would look something like this:

```
@RestController
public class UserFilterController {


    @GetMapping(path = "/api1")
    public ResponseEntity filterUserWithApi1(String x, String y, String z, String age, String location) {

        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/api2")
    public ResponseEntity filterUserWithApi2(String a, String b, String c, String age, String location) {

        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/api3")
    public ResponseEntity filterUserWithApi3(String d, String e, String f, String age, String location) {

        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/api4")
    public ResponseEntity filterUserWithApi4(String g, String s, String h, String age, String location) {

        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/api5")
    public ResponseEntity filterUserWithApi5(String j, String k, String l, String age, String location) {

        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you please share controller definition

Comment: @silentsudo, I have added the controller to the post.

Comment: i have added my response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know how many params will be there in request you can use @RequestParam as Map like below -

```
@GetMapping(path = "/api1")
public void test(@RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters) {
    //TODO
    String value1 = parameters.get("key1");
    ........
}
```

And you can pass these params as below -

```
/api1?key1=value1&key2=value2...
```

OR -

```
@GetMapping(path = "/api1/{age}/{location}")
public ResponseEntity filterUserWithApi1(@PathVariable("age") String age,
                                         @PathVariable("location") String location,
                                         @RequestParam("x") String x,
                                         @RequestParam("y") String y,
                                         @RequestParam("z") String z) {
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Request -

```
/api1/24/earth?x=x_value&y=y_value&z=z_value
```

OR-

```
@GetMapping(path = "/api1/{age}/{location}/{x}/{y}/{z}")
public ResponseEntity filterUserWithApi1(@PathVariable("age") String age,
                                         @PathVariable("location") String location,
                                         @PathVariable("x") String x,
                                         @PathVariable("y") String y,
                                         @PathVariable("z") String z) 
{
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

REQUEST -

```
/api1/<age_value>/<location_value>/<x_value>/<y_value>/<z_value>
```

Comment: this will lead to numerous null checks and and error prone code will be present in controller, it is always best to make sure what is controller consuming leaving it for client with as many and as much might be a house with open door and window.

Comment: @silentsudo agreed.

Comment: @silentsudo I have updated the answer with multiple options, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the path it's not the same, you don't need to set the `params` field in the `@GetMapping` annotation, you can simply do :

```
@GetMapping(path = "/api1")
public void myFunction( @RequestParam("age") String age, @RequestParam("location") String location, ... ) {
...
}
```

If it's the same path, you can also do that, but you will need to add "required=false" in the RequestParam annotation and handle manually what to do when some fields are present or not

Comment: Thanks @Prim, I only used the param field for readability purpose in this post. In my code I'm using the structure you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your query parameter is a single attribute which has number of values and age/location are some other mandatory query param which is present at the end. This is how I will write the controller known the given parameters

```
         @GetMapping(path = "/test")
        public Map<String, String> test(@RequestParam("alphabets") Set<String> alphabets,
                                        @RequestParam("age") int age,
                                        @RequestParam("location") String location) {
            final Map<String, String> responseMap = new HashMap<>();
            responseMap.put("alphabets", alphabets.toString());
            responseMap.put("age", Integer.toString(age));
            responseMap.put("location", location);
            return responseMap;
        }
```

The invocation of this controller looks like this

```
http://localhost:8080/test?alphabets=a&age=1&location=test
http://localhost:8080/test?alphabets=a,b,c&age=1&location=test
```

Now you can create the junction based on the values present in the alphabets.

Thank you.